# Select e inner join

Tags: php, mysql

Estou com um problema, não consigo fazer a consulta ao `mysql` retornar o dados do `id=4` do perfil, sendo que ao utilizar a `query` abaixo:

```
select p.*, ec.nome as estado_civil_nome , t.nome as titulo_nome,
        uo.nome as uf_oab_nome from perfil p
        inner join estado_civil ec on(p.estado_civil_id = ec.id)
        inner join titulo t on(p.titulo_id = t.id) 
        inner join uf_oab uo on(p.uf_oab_id = uo.id)
        where p.id = {$id};
```

A resposta é:

```
MySQL não retornou nenhum registo. (A consulta demorou 0,0000 segundos.)
```

Sendo que o `id=4` existe no banco de dados!

Fiz um `echo($query)` e mostrou o seguinte resultado:

```
select p.*, ec.nome as estado_civil_nome , t.nome as titulo_nome, uo.nome as 
uf_oab_nome from perfil p inner join estado_civil ec on(p.estado_civil_id = 
ec.id) inner join titulo t on(p.titulo_id = t.id) inner join uf_oab uo 
on(p.uf_oab_id = uo.id) where p.id = 4
```

Onde estou errando?

Comment: como você está usando inner join, o Id 4 tem que existir em todas as tabelas, caso contrário não retornará dados, você chegou se o Id 4 está em todas as tabelas (todas utilizadas join) ?

Comment: Você precisa de todos os registros dessas tabelas ou pode trocar o `inner join` por um `left join` ?

Comment: Obrigado pelo retorno Edvaldo e Ronaldo, estes registros fazem parte do cadastro do perfil do usuário, neste caso eu estou enviando um id=4 para resgatar todos os dados da tabela perfil e exibir em uma página alguns dados para que o cliente possa alterar. Todos esses  dados são utilizados em 3 formulários, um com :Nome, nacionalidade, estado civil, rg, cpf, e data de nascimento , outra com os dados referente ao perfil academico e outra com os dados profissionais. Tudo extraído da mesma tabela

Comment: Edvaldo o id 4 é o id da tabela perfil. As tabelas que compõe o inner join não possuem o id do perfil

Comment: Ronaldo na verdade eu faço alteração em 3 etapas posso usar o left join para cada etapa? Isso faria meu sql funcionar?

Answer (score 0):

graças a luz dos colegas Edvaldo e Ronaldo, consegui resolver meu problema.
Simplesmente alterando o INNER JOIN para LEFT JOIN, desta forma, ao consultar (busca), o mysql compara a tabela (left) 'perfil' com as tabelas (right) 'estado_civil', 'titulo' e uf_oab, caso não consiga fazer a comparação ele retorna 'null' para as tabelas da direita (right), podemos assim preencher estes campos com null quando da alteração. Bons estudos a todos!